# $|x-a| < \epsilon$ , $|y-a| < \epsilon$ (where $x,y,a\in\mathbb R $ and $\epsilon>0$). Use the Triangle Inequality to find an estimate for $|x-y|$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, formal-proofs, triangle-inequality

I am teaching myself Real Analysis.  I have done proofs in Discrete Mathematics, Linear Algebra, and Abstract Algebra.  Nothing too difficult, mainly elementary and intermediate kinds!  For this problem, I will lay out my thought process and explain where I am stuck at.  If someone could please explain, in a clear manner, what to do OR giving me a hint, that would be helpful!

My thought:

Consider $|x-a| < \epsilon$.  If we add $-|y-a|$ to both sides of the inequality, then the inequality maintains order and we have $|x-a| - |y-a| < \epsilon -|y-a|$.  By the Triangle Inequality, we can see that $|x-a| - |y-a| \leq |x-y|$.

Now this is where I am stuck.  I am not quite sure on how to explain if $|x-y| < \epsilon - |y-a|$, $|x-y| \leq \epsilon - |y-a|$, or if there is something else I am missing.

Any help explained clearly would be kindly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  $|x-y|\le|x-a|+|y-a|=2\epsilon$

Comment: You can draw the real line, place the point $a$ and place $x$ and $y$ at a distance of at most $\epsilon$ of $a$. Then you'll find the answer of J. W. Tanner.

Comment: Just a bit different than what @J.W.Tanner said,  $|x-y| \le |x-a| + |a-y | = 2e$.

Answer (score 3):

Using the triangle inequality,

$|x-y|=|(x-a)+(a-y)|\le|x-a|+|a-y|=|x-a|+|y-a|\lt \epsilon + \epsilon=2\epsilon$.

---

Alternatively $|x-a|<\epsilon$ and $|y-a|<\epsilon\iff a-\epsilon<x<a+\epsilon$ and $a-\epsilon<y<a+\epsilon\iff$

$ a-\epsilon<x<a+\epsilon$ and $-a-\epsilon<-y<-a+\epsilon\implies-2\epsilon<x-y<2\epsilon\iff|x-y|<2\epsilon$.

Comment: Thank you for the welcome J.W. Tanner!  I also appreciate your reply!  It helps a lot!  Your second comment is what I was trying to go for (use the hypothesis to reach a conclusion), but I was not using a theorem you used.   I am bummed I overthought the problem, but at least I am learning!

Answer (score 0):

$|x-y| = |(x-a) + (a-y)| \le |x-a| + |a-y| < 2\epsilon$.

That's the easy part. You did the hard part that I, personally, *always* screw up.

Actually ... you say "we have |x−a|−|y−a|<ϵ−|y−a|. By the Triangle Inequality, we can see that |x−a|−|y−a|≤|x−y|".  Could you explain why?  Is $|x-y| \ge \epsilon -|y-a|$?  why do you have strict inequality?  How can you justify that?

Let me try and let's hope I don't screw up.

$|x-a|= |(x-y)+(y-a)| \le |x-y|+|y-a|$

$|x-a|-|y-a| \le |x-y|$.

Of course if $|x-a| < |y-a|$ the left hand side is negative and the result is trivial but we could just as easily proven $|y-a| = |(y-x) +(x-a)| \le |x-y| -|x-a|$ and concluded $|y-a| -|x-a| \le |x-y|$.

So $0\le ||x-a| -|y-a|| \le |x-y| < 2\epsilon$.

Comment: Hi fleablood!  Thank you for helping!  

1) My thought process was that from |x-a| - |y-a| < epsilon - |y-a|, if we looked at the left hand side of the inequality, |x-a| - |y-a|, with a little bit of manipulation, we could set up another inequality, where |x-a| <= |x-y| + |y-a| (where the Triangle Inequality came into play), and then I would subtract |y-a| from both sides of the inequality to get |x-a| - |y-a| <= |x-y|.  I was not sure about the strict inequality (or if it was a different inequality sign).  I definitely overthought this problem, and feel bummed about my thought process.